# Função equivalente ao trim (função para remover espaços extras no início e fim) no Python?

Tags: python, string

No PHP e JavaScript, temos a função `trim` que serve para aparar uma `string`, removendo espaços extras no início e no final.

Assim:

```
 $str = ' meu nome é wallace ';
 var_dump(trim($str)); // string('meu nome é wallace')
```

Como é que posso fazer isso no Python?

Não consegui encontrar nenhuma função parecida com `trim`.

Comment: print "_".join(celula.encode('utf-8').strip().lower().split())
uso essa função para remover o "_"

Comment: Parece muita operação para uma coisa simples @GuilhermeLima

Comment: por que realmente ele faz muita coisa, utf8, lowercase...

Comment: Esse negócio de setar utf8 é necessário no python? Tá parecendo coisa de  PHP (não tenho nada contra php, eu o amo :D)

Comment: @WallaceMaxters tudo no Python é Unicode por padrão. Pra falar a verdade, acho que não.

Comment: na realidade não precisa, foi uma situação especifica.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

### .strip

De acordo com o [manual](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods), há o método `.strip()`:

```
minhaString.strip()
```

Se precisar especificar os caracteres a serem removidos, como apenas espaços, deixando tabs e quebras de linha, pode usar assim:

```
minhaString.strip(" ")
```

Notar que neste segundo caso, se você especificar vários caracteres, eles são tratados individualmente:

```
"tomate seco".strip("otm")
```

Retorno:

```
ate sec
```

### .rstrip e .lstrip

Se precisar remover só à esquerda, tem o `.lstrip()`:

```
"banana".lstrip( "abc" )
```

Retorno:

```
nana
```

e se precisar remover só à direita, tem o `.rstrip()`:

```
"banana".lstrip( "a" )
```

Retorno:

```
banan
```

O *default* do `.rstrip` e do `.lstrip` também é remover caracteres de espaçamento, como tabulações e quebras de linha.

### *Deprecated*

Só pra constar, isso existiu como função:

```
string.strip( string [, caracteres] )
```

Funcionava da mesma forma que descrito acima, mas a *string* era o 1º argumento da chamada, e o segundo, opcional, os caracteres a se remover. Da mesma forma, se omitido, referia-se aos espaços em branco, tabulações e quebras de linha.

<sub>estou me referindo no passado, mas vai funcionar enquanto não for removido de fato.</sub>

Comment: A sua resposta também é importante. No PHP tem o `ltrim` e `rtrim`, que é o trim a direita e a esquerda. +1

Answer (score 11):

Não tem função com o nome de `trim()` mas tem a `strip()` que faz o trabalho equivalente. Ela remove os caracteres  `\n, \r, \t, \f, espaço`

```
" meu nome é wallace ".strip()
```

**Baseado em**: [Trimming a string in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6039813/1342547)

Comment: Mais rápido que o @Bacco e que os meteoros de pégasus

Comment: Pois é. só restaurei a minha por causa do lstrip, mas no strip "seco" o @rray ganhou. E já upei tb.

Comment: Só não pode falar que o @rray ou eu somos bons no .strip, senão vai soar meio esquisito.

Comment: hahaha @Bacco, isso se aplica apenas em strings :P.

Comment: desde que não pensem em g-strings tá ótimo :D

Answer (score 5):

O que você procura é o [.strip()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.strip). Ele é responsável por remover espaços no início e o final, como o `trim()`.

```
' meu nome é wallace '.strip()
```

Você possui outras opções, como o [.replace()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace).

```
str= ' meu nome é wallace '
str.replace(" ", "")
```

Lembrando que dessa forma retirará todos, não  só o início e fim, como o `trim`.

Lembrando também que em python também possui [.rstrip()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.rstrip) e [.lstrip()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.lstrip), para remoção de caracteres a direita e esquerda, respectivamente.

Como a pergunta é sobre **PHP > Python**, existe o site [php2python](http://www.php2python.com/wiki/function.trim/) exatamente para isso.

Fontes:
[Trimming a string in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/761825/4843158)
[How to trim whitespace (including tabs)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1185524/4843158)
[Manual Python](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.lstrip)

Answer (score 3):

Complementando.

Para remover todos os *espaços em branco* você pode usar o `join` e o `split` como sugerido nos comentários pelo **Guilherme Lima**, veja o exemplo:

```
s = " Stack Over Flow "
s = ''.join(s.split())

print s
```

Saída:`StackOverFlow`

Ou uma expressão regular:

```
import re

s = " Stack Over Flow "    
pattern = re.compile(r'\s+')    
s = re.sub(pattern, '', s)    
print s
```

Saída: `StackOverFlow`

E para remover apenas espaços em branco no começo e no fim da string use o `strip` como sugerido pelos usuários **rray**, **Bacco** e **Randrade**:

```
s = " Stack Over Flow "

s = s.strip()

print s
```

Saída: `Stack Over Flow`

Consulte a documentação do módulo [re](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#module-re) para aprende mais.
Consulte a documentação a respeito de [operações comuns em string](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html) para aprender mais a respeito dos comandos `join`, `split` e `strip`.

Fonte:
[Python remove all whitespace in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8270124/5429980)

Answer (score 2):

Para fazer uma função trim em python que sirva para aparar string, removendo espaços extras no início e no final, basta usar Expressão Regular indicando espaço em branco no final (r'\s+$') e no começo da String (r'^\s+'), veja:

Entrada: " Stack Over Flow "

```
import re

s = " Stack Over Flow "
print "'"+s+"'"
pattern = re.compile(r'\s+$')    
s = re.sub(pattern, '', s)
pattern = re.compile(r'^\s+')
s = re.sub(pattern, '', s)
print "'"+s+"'"
```

Saída: "Stack Over Flow"